# subquery row count form two table join

Tags: mysql, subquery

My two table like this

1. subject table

```
-----------------------
|id  | subject_name  |
-----------------------
|1   |math           |
-----------------------
|2   |English        |
-----------------------
```

2. question table

```
-----------------------------------------
|id  | subject_id    | qustion
------------------------------------------
|1   |1              | some questin1
------------------------------------------
|3   |1              | some questin1
------------------------------------------
|4   |2              | some questin1
------------------------------------------
|5   |2              | some questin1
------------------------------------------
|6   |2              | some questin1
------------------------------------------
```

I want like this form question table

```
Math 2 row
English 3 row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Join and aggregation clause here  -

```
SELECT S.subject_name,
       CONCAT(COUNT (questions.question), 'Rows')
FROM subject S
JOIN questions Q ON S.id = Q.subject_id
GROUP BY subject.subject_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT subject.subject_name, COUNT (questions.question)
FROM subject JOIN questions ON subject.id = questions.subject_id;
```